# Changing stroke color of LineSeries and/or AreaSeries in LightningChart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

Is it possible to change the stroke color of LineSeries and/or AreaSeries in LightningChart JS based on point values?
Example 1: Display the line as red when the y-value is above 10.0, but use blue color otherwise.
Example 2: Display the line as yellow when x-value is between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as current version 3.2 goes, no this is not possible (unless you construct each line segment point A -> point B manually using `SegmentSeries` and assign the colors yourself, but this will not be performant with even as little as 1000 data points or so).

`PointSeries` supports assigning a `PalettedFill` which can be used to color data points based on X or Y coordinates which would serve your needs.

Adding `PalettedFill` support for `LineSeries` and `AreaSeries` is on our bucket list and will likely be included in the next version after 2-3 months.

If this feature missing is a show stopper for you then please [contact us](https://www.arction.com/contact/) for specialized service.

Otherwise, we'll update this thread once the feature is out.